# Select feature base on another feature

Tags: mapinfo

right now i am working in "MapInfo 10.0" tool where i stuck in a situation. I have a "GPS track" and "existing roads". Now i just want to select those roads where GPS track is present. The problem is there is no common attributes between these features.

My idea : GPS buffer and select features within the desired radius or distance.

Is there a way or tool to do such task or it would be done by coding?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do this using MapInfo's SQL Select. For example, this would select any road objects within 50m of a GPS track point:

`Select * from Roads where obj intersects Any(Select Buffer(obj, 10, 50, "m") from Tracks)`

To change the buffer radius you just need to change the third parameter (currently 50) in the Buffer function above.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, actually i tried it and it worked really well, but the problem is, it also select those roads which are in range of the track buffer. Is there a way to neglect those roads which are partially selected through buffer region ??

Comment: You can change the spatial join from `intersects` to `within` to only select objects whose *centroids* are within the buffer regions. I can't remember 100% and haven't got time to check right now but you may be able to use `entirely within` to ensure the whole object is contained within the buffer.

Comment: The prob has been solved, thanks for the needful advice sir. #GodBlessYou :)